# jquery - select input with given name and value from radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to display a div tag, if the user selects option 4 from radiobuttion.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#GenderInAnotherWay").hide();

    $("input[name='Gender'][value=4]").prop("checked", true);{
        $("#GenderInAnotherWay").toggle();
    });
})
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Comment: Something is wrong with your code. Why is there a block after `$("input[name='Gender'][value=4]").prop("checked", true);` and an unbalanced `)` after that?

Comment: Why has my question been down voted?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve] - it is voted down because at  SO we do not feel like writing our own test case. Click  the `<>` snippet editor and create a working example

Answer (score 1):

try it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#GenderInAnotherWay").hide();
    $("input[name='Gender']").change(function() {
        if(parseInt(this.value) == 4) {
            $("#GenderInAnotherWay").show();
        } else {
            $("#GenderInAnotherWay").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: DRY! `$("#GenderInAnotherWay").toggle(this.value === '4');`

Comment: Also don't make snippets that do not run

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#GenderInAnotherWay").hide();

    $("input[name='Gender']").click(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 4) {
          $("#GenderInAnotherWay").show()
       } else {
          $("#GenderInAnotherWay").hide();
       }
    });
})
```

Comment: Nice one! You can also remove the jQuery in the `if` : `if (this.checked && this.value == 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if($("input[name='Gender']:checked").val() == 4)
$('#myDiv').toggle();
```

Comment: `$("#mydiv").toggle($("input[name='Gender']:checked").val() == 4)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using values instead of name, based on the first line of your question (and nothing else)

```js
$("#selectElement").on("change", function()
{
  //if selected option's value is 'gender'
  if($(this).val() == "Gender")
  { 
    //show the div (and append text)
    $("#secondDiv").show();
    $("#secondDiv").append( "Div created and this text inserted" );
  }
  else
  {
    //otherwise hide the div and remove all child elements from it
    $("#secondDiv").hide();
    $("#secondDiv").empty();
  }
});
```

```css
div
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="firstDiv">
  <select id="selectElement">
    <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Gender">Gender</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="secondDiv" hidden="hidden"></div>
```